# Box-shadow for columnspan

Tags: html, css, reactjs

Recently I've found the need to add a box-shadow to a column in a table. The easiest way I've found was to create a column span and add a class in which I defined the box-shadow property.

Problem is the shadow is not being displayed.

My code looks something like this:

```css
.box-shadow-column {
  box-shadow: -1px 0 0 0 red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <colgroup>
    <col/>
    <col/>
    <col/>
    <col className="box-shadow-column" />
    <col/>
  </colgroup>
  <tr>
    <th>Column 1</th>
    <th>Column 2</th>
    <th>Column 3</th>
    <th>Column 4</th>
    <th>Column 5</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Some text</td>
    <td>Some text</td>
    <td>Some text</td>
    <td>Some text</td>
    <td>Some text</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

```
.box-shadow-column {
  box-shadow:  -1px 0 0 0 red;
}

<colgroup>
     <col/>
     <col/>
     <col/>
     <col className="box-shadow-column"/>
     <col/>
</colgroup>
```

As a side note I'm working with Gatsby.

Fixing the typo pointed by David does not resolve the issue.

Comment: `.box-shadow-colum` Your CSS selector is missing the `n` at the end.

Comment: The attribute in the `col` tag is `class` not `className`